# Chosen library disables validation of DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-chosen

In my ASP.NET MVC project the javascript Chosen library will disable the validation for the DropDownList. I referenced below validation scripts in layout page:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

and the part of my view is as below:

```
<div class="col-md-10" align="right" style="margin-top: 30px">
   @Html.DropDownList("ProvinceId", null, "- استان را انتخاب نمایید- ", new { required = "true", type = "Text", @class = "form-control" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProvinceId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-10" align="right" style="margin-top: 30px" id="divcities">
   @Html.DropDownList("CityId", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "- شهر را انتخاب نمایید -", new { type = "Text", @class = "form-control" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

and some part of my jquery code in this view is as below:

```
@section Scripts{
     <script>

        $('form').validate({

            rules: {
                ProvinceId: {
                    required: true,
                },
                CityId: {
                    required: true,
                }
            },
            messages: {
                ProvinceId: {
                    required: "استان را انتخاب نمایید",
                },
                CityId: {
                    required: "شهر را انتخاب نمایید",
                },
            }
        });

    </script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#ProvinceId, #CityId").chosen();
        })
    </script>
    }
```

I must say that all of other validation will work but the validations for this two fields do not work. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by putting   **ignore: [ ]**, at the end of below script:

```
   <script>

    $('form').validate({

        rules: {
            ProvinceId: {
                required: true,
            },
            CityId: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            ProvinceId: {
                required: "استان را انتخاب نمایید",
            },
            CityId: {
                required: "شهر را انتخاب نمایید",
            },
        },
        ignore: [],
    });

</script>
```